# Validation HTML Radio Button 

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, radio-button

I am facing a problem with simple validating of radio button though database.

What I want to do is to just simply check whether radio button for each question is selected or not. I know the simple checking. But as I am using php variable name for every radio button name, it's very hard to convert to javascript variable and check. And I am stuck at this point.

```
<form id="formID" method="post" action="user_anger_quiz.php?rating_finished=true">

<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $question_form_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $question_id ?>,1"/>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $question_form_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $question_id ?>,2" />

<p id="anger_rating_submit">
<input type="submit" value="Rate my anger level"/></p>
  </form>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated in advanced.

Comment: Can you give us a little more info on what you mean. Are you checking the radio buttons against correct answers in a db table? or checking them statically. Or when you say validating, do you mean that your code is broken? Can we see some more output?

Comment: I want to check the users check the radio button or not. thx

Comment: You would need to use some javascript. This thread should get you started : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325924/radio-button-validation-dynamic-name

Answer (score 1):

regarding to your comment:

I guess that you will use php to check it due to the fact that you just add php as a tag.
In php you can use $_POST or $_GET on action page of your form to fetch the radio buttons.

Otherwise you can use javascript / javascript library

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking to make sure there is a radio button checked before submitting? Try the below untested function using jquery to see if there is a radio button selected.  Run that before the form is submitted.

```
function somethingChecked()
{
    if (!$("input[name='<?php echo $question_form_name; ?>']:checked").val()) {
        alert('You need to check something');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```